# cakephp 3.x routing to subfolders

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.0

On my website I have the usual routes for

```
website.com
website.com/pages/about
website.com/img/116633
...
```

Now I have these pages

```
website.com/username/mike
website.com/username/john
website.com/username/eric
...
```

which should become

```
website.com/mike
website.com/john
website.com/eric
...
```

my routing goes like this:

```
$routes->connect(
    '/*',
    ['controller' => 'username', 'action' => 'index'],
    ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']
);
```

And this works, but all other pages like

```
website.com/pages/about
website.com/img/116633
```

are broken (they take the 'controller' => 'username')

what is the best way to make this happen?

Below my full routes.php

```
    Router::defaultRouteClass('Route');

Router::extensions(['html', 'rss', 'pdf']);

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Search', 'action' => 'start']);

    $routes->connect('/start', ['controller' => 'Search', 'action' => 'start']);

    $routes->connect(
        '/*',
        ['controller' => 'username', 'action' => 'index'],
        ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']
    );

    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});




Router::connect('/img/*', ['controller' => 'Pic', 'action' => 'item']);

Router::url([
    'controller' => 'Pages',
    'action' => 'lang',
    '_base' => 'false'
]);



Router::addUrlFilter(function ($params, $request) {
    if (isset($request->params['lang']) && !isset($params['lang'])) {
        $params['lang'] = $request->params['lang'];
    }
    return $params;
});


Plugin::routes();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $routes->connect(
    '/*',
    ['controller' => 'username', 'action' => 'index'],
    ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']
);
```

has to be replaced with:

```
$routes->connect(
    '/:username',
    ['controller' => 'Username', 'action' => 'index'],
    [
      'pass' => ['username'],
        'username'  => '[0-9a-zA-Z]+'
    ]
);
```

This passes the username from the URL to the `index()` in the `Username` controller.

For more information: [Route Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action) and [Passing parameters to Action](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action).

Comment: This is why an example works 100 times better for me than a theoretical explanation. Thanks!